# Equation worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

## Example equation

Let's say I have the following equation:

`A = B - C - D`

If I know any three variables, I can solve for the fourth. The expressions for the other variables are:

```
B = A + C + D

C = B - A - D

D = B - C - A
```

## Worksheet

If there are numbers in columns `B`, `C`, and `D`, `A` can be calculated via:

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(B2),ISNUMBER(C2),ISNUMBER(D2)), B2-C2-D2)
```

The formulas for the other columns are similar:

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(A2),ISNUMBER(C2),ISNUMBER(D2)), A2+C2+D2)

=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(B2),ISNUMBER(A2),ISNUMBER(D2)), B2-A2-D2)

=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(B2),ISNUMBER(A2),ISNUMBER(C2)), B2-A2-C2)
```

## Result

This appears to work fine. In the below screenshot:

- row 2 : A is calculated
- row 3 : B is calculated
- row 4 : C is calculated
- row 5 : D is calculated

[image]

## Drawbacks

If I drag the formulas down to new rows, the values are populated with numbers, likely due to the circular dependencies involved:

[image]

You can also see the blue arrow indicating a circular reference.

## Question

The above method basically works. However, it has the drawbacks mentioned above.

Is there a better approach to implementing this kind of equation solver technique?

## Worksheet Link

Here's a link to the example worksheet if you'd like to experiment with it:

https://1drv.ms/x/s!AjlM3TqVAvfOh84TMHQWg4G6qeDpbw?e=68Y7do

Comment: As you stated you can only solve knowing 3 of the 4 values. The formulas you have will only work AFTER you input 3 of the 4 values. Before that it give you nonsense values.

Comment: @gns100 Is there a way to perhaps have them display as empty before the user enters a number?

Comment: I don't think that is possible with formulas, but I've been wrong before. What I think you need to do is separate your "input" section from your "output" section. So, the input would be the 3 of 4 given values, and the output would be formula(s) which provide the solution if 3 values are given. Good luck.